A SF short story (probably by Asimov) about a neutron star with a pun: "star mangled spanner"
I found out recently about a short story (probably by Asimov) about a neutron star. It was mentioned in a discussion about puns, and in particular "star mangled spanner", which even being French, I understood as a twisted reference to the US national flag.
But the title of this SF story was not mentioned.  My question, on-topic, is what is the title of the story that contains this pun.
What comes below is off-topic but it is not my question. It is just incidental.
Another pun was mentioned, about a non-fiction book by Asimov, "A Double Planet" which is about Pluton and Chiron, not Earth and Moon. But in the discussion there is a mention a pun in that book about Earth being a double planet not because of the Moon, but because it is "pear shaped".
If anyone is kind enough to explain this pun to a poor Frenchman, maybe in a comment, I'll be very grateful.

The only thing I can think of on the Double Planet joke is that "pair" implies double and the pun is on "pear". But that is pretty awful.

Speaking of pear-thetic puns, there's a French song (& album) called A Bird on a Poire, punning on Leonard Cohen's A Bird on a Wire.

"pear shaped"  might possibly be a reference to "The Liberation of Earth" by William Tenn. The Earth is repeatedly conquered by aliens, then "liberated" by other aliens who become the new rulers, then liberated again by the first aliens. Much of the planet is destroyed, leaving Earth literally pear shaped.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Liberation_of_Earth

@OrganicMarble  A bit weak, yes, but better than nothing.

@Pete I understand this probable origin of the expression "pear-shaped". Indeed, Earth is an oblate ellipsoid rather than a perfect sphere, but this does not make it "pear shaped". But what about the pun ? My comment to Organic Marble seems to have disap-pear-ed, I had to repost it.

The exact language Asimov used can be seen at https://galacticjourney.org/stories/6209FSF.pdf, page 99. He describes how scientists had recently discovered that the southern part of the earth's equatorial region bulges a bit more than the northern part, and so those scientists used the word "pear-shaped" to describe the planet. And then he talks about The Double Planet and a contrived scenario where he gets to joke that the earth is a double planet because it's pair-shaped (as @OrganicMarble guessed). He does seem to recognize that it's a bad pun.

@Max Thank you for your very detailed answer. I don't think that the notion of a "bad pun" exists for Asimov. Consider 'Death of a Foy"... https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2878/what-is-asimovs-joke-in-death-of-a-foy

The first Google Search result for "star mangled spanner" is the Wikipedia page for Clarke's novel (just sayin').

Not Asimov, Arthur C. Clarke.
The story is "Neutron Tide".
It ends

"The only identifiable fragment of the pride of the United States Navy was - one star-mangled spanner."

You can read it in the original Galaxy publication at the Luminist Archive, but I wouldn't bother. It's a two-page lame joke story.

Yes, it fits the description of the story in that discussion. The name of the author was a pure conjecture, because Asimov is a well known author of "Feghoots"

I can't (yet) comment, else I would, but note also that "spanner" is a British-ism, and not usually seen in American English. Thus Clarke, not Asimov. (The latter probably wished he'd thought of it first, though.)

" but I wouldn't bother."  Why not?  It's a quick read and worth a chuckle.

There's more funny stuff in there than just the pun.  There's the Russian spaceship Lieutenant Kizhe.  The ship from which the "star mangled spanner" came was the Flatbush, poking at the US - appropriated from the native Americans, developed using slave labor.  The British ship "Insufferable" as a comment on British attitudes.

@JRE humor is a funny thing.
